# Safari Desktop and Mobile: Image overlayed by canvas is very blurry

Tags: ios, html, css, canvas

I have an image that is overlayed by a canvas. Both image and canvas are wrapped in a div that is scaled. When drawing on the canvas the image gets very blurry. Do you have any ideas how to get rid of the blur? 
Please see this fiddle:

```
<body>

    <div style="position: relative;  transform: scaleX(2) scaleY(2) ">

        <div class="pagecontainer" style=" width: 125px; height: 100px; position: absolute; top:0px; left:400px">
            <img src="http://www.maxrev.de/files/2011/02/testbild_1297949508.jpg" width="125" height="100" >
        </div>

        <div style="position: absolute; left: 400px; top:0px;width: 125px; height:150px;">
            <canvas id="supercanvas" width="125" height="150" style="width:125px; height:125px"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
     document.getElementById("supercanvas").getContext("2d").fillRect(80, 80, 80, 80);
    </script>
</body>
```

[image: iOS Test - drawing on canvas]

[image: iOS Test - not drawing on canvas]

Comment: If its a retina display then CSS pixels are larger than physical pixels. Set the canvas resolution (`canvas.width` & `canvas.height`) to twice the display size (`canvas.style.width` & `canvas.style.height`). You can use `devicePixelRatio` to find out how large CSS pixel are compared to physical pixel size, though it also reports the page's zoom setting.

Comment: Combine retina display + your CSS zoom and you actually have one pixel of your canvas dispatched on 4 physical pixels.